# Does it matter what objects I launch in Control?

Tags: control

In *Control*, the player has the ability to pick up and launch objects at enemies. If there's no grabbable object nearby, Jesse breaks off a piece of the floor instead, meaning you never have to go looking for something to throw.

Does it matter what objects I launch at enemies in *Control*? Do different objects do different amounts of damage? Or can I just launch anything without thinking?

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter what you launch at enemies. Anything you pick up will be launched with the same force and will do the same damage, which is only increased by putting points into the launch skills that say they increase damage.

The only exception is when you catch and return explosives, those keep their regular damage instead of using the standard projectile damage. But as far as I've seen, their damage is pretty close to projectile damage.

Comment: Another exception appears to be fire extinguishers, which explode when thrown

Comment: You can also launch enemies, at higher levels. Do enemies count as regular projectiles, or do they add additional bonuses?

Comment: From what I've seen, the regular enemies count as regular projectiles but you do get the bonus of both the thrown and the target enemies take damage. If I remember correctly, you can throw "large" enemies at the highest levels of the skill, but I haven't tested with them so I don't know if that changes the damage values.

Comment: There's an upgrade that allows you to launch larger objects. If object size doesn't matter, what is the use of the upgrade?

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, I'm not sure if a thrown enemy does more damage or not if it is considered "large." But this does not mean specific size matters, just if an enemy is considered large or normal, where both categories do a specific amount of damage regardless of the exact size within the category. The upgrade still helps because being able to throw more enemies means there are less enemies you try to throw and fail, wasting time and energy in combat.

Comment: I'm not referring to the enemy size upgrade. There is a separate ability "[Launch Strength: Launch large objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keoWi.jpg)"

Comment: My mistake. I don't have an answer to that question.